# Delphi 2007 OpenPictureDialog.Execute causes abrupt program termination

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2007

I have an application developed in Delphi 2007.  This program is very old, with several thousand users.  One customer, and only one that I can determine, is experiencing an abrupt program termination when the following code is executed on Windows 10.

```
procedure TFmSF5Main.dxOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  LastFilterIndex : integer = 1;
var
  Dlg : TOpenDialog;
  MyVar : integer;
begin
  Dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    Dlg.Filter := 'Tiff Files (*.tif,*.tiff) | *.tiff;*.tif|'+
                  'Jpeg Files (*.jpg,*.jpeg) | *.jpg;*.jpeg|'+
                  'Bmp Files (*.bmp) | *.bmp|'+
                  'PDF Files (*.pdf) | *.pdf|'+
                  'PNG Files (*.png) | *.png|'+
                  'DICOM Files (*.dicom,*.dcm) | *.dicom;*.dcm|'+
                  'Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt|'+
                  'APF Files (*.apf) | *.apf|'+
                  'Open Office Text (*.odt) | *.odt|' +
                  'Open Office SpreadSheet (*.ods) | *.ods|' +
                  'All Files (*.*) | *.*';
    Dlg.FilterIndex := LastFilterIndex;
    if Dlg.Execute(self.handle) then
    begin
      OtherMRU.AddItem(Dlg.FileName,nil);
      SaveMRUItems(mruOther);
      LastFilterIndex := Dlg.FilterIndex;
      ProcessOpenCommand(Dlg.FileName);
      FBookMarkNode := nil;
      btnBack.enabled := false;
    end;
  finally
    Dlg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Any clues as to what would cause this?  No complaints from other customers.  I have not changed the `Dialogs.UseLatestCommonDialogs` variable, so it is at the default value of `True`.

Comment: `LastFilterIndex` is declared as a local `const`, but you are trying to re-assign a value to it at runtime that persists between multiple calls to `dxOpenClick()`. That will not work unless [Writable Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Writeable_typed_constants_(Delphi)) is enabled (which is not a good thing to do, which is why it is OFF by default). `LastFilterIndex` should be made into a member of the `TFmSF5Main` class instead.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted here that would cause that issue, which means the problem is in other than the code here. What do `SaveMRUItems` and `ProcessOpenCommand` look like? (I use `TOpenDialog` in several D2007 apps on a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines without issue.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The question says *the following code*. It doesn't say it's on the `Execute` call.

Comment: @KenWhite no, the *code* doesn't, but the *title* of this question does. But then, the title also says `OpenPictureDialog` but the code says `TOpenDialog` instead.

Comment: As this is only an issue for one user, I suspect the the issue is on their PC, possibly due to a flaky Explorer plug in. Try creating a minimal example app, with just an open dialog, and also presetting the initial folder to something other than the default. But Remy's comment could be significant

Comment: the dialog never shows so I presume it is in the execute call.  Cannot reproduce the problem here on windows 10 as well.  Writeable constants is enabled.  I doubt the other functions calls have anything to do with it but the SaveMRUItems just saves to a string list and processopencommand only opens the file and loads it into a TImageEnMView.  The same problem exists in another portion of the application where Savedialog.execute causes abrupt termination.  These issues not experienced by other users, only this particular one.

Comment: Make a minimal app to narrow it down. But yes, shell extension is a likely suspect

Comment: I would also agree with others about strong possibly that the affected user probably has some explorer extension which causes issues. I have already heard of similar problems but I must admit I haven't encountered one myself thou.

Comment: It is certainly a Windows explorer extension that is the problem.  I gave the customer a modified build where I set uselatestcommondialogs to false and she could see the old style dialog without a problem.  I had further provided her with a modified version using the GetOpenFileName api directly so that I could get the return code for further inspection, however she has not done that as she promised, so I cannot analyze the problem further.